# Can a simulacrum "regain" HP by being True Polymorphed into a creature that can do so normally?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, hit-points, simulacrum

If a simulacrum is polymorphed through True Polymorph into a creature that can regain hit points normally, can the simulacrum regain hit points while polymorphed in that way?

Comment: @Someone_Evil AL tag might be relevant if there are, or ever woll be, specific limitations about that matter in organized play. And if there are none, saying it explicitly would help, too. Thus, I believe that al tag might be useful, or at least not harmful.

Comment: Related: [Simulacrum with regeneration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/121755/28591)

Comment: The question doesn't mention AL organized play, and tags aren't used to add restrictions to a question (they're for categorization and attracting expert opinion), so I've removed the AL tag.

Comment: As to the content of the question: Your first paragraph is a very clear question, but I'm not sure what the second paragraph means. It looks to me like the question in the first paragraph is what you really care about. I would remove the second paragraph and focus on the first question. Then, depending on the answer to that question, you can address any other concerns by posting a follow-up question separately.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Yes, and no.

The *simulacrum's* statistics are **replaced**. This means you take whatever form of record sheet you're using for the *simulacrum*, put it aside, and grab the stat block of the creature you've *polymorphed* it into and use that while the *polymorph* effect persists.

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its alignment and personality.

While *[polymorphed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph)*, the creature is a tyrannosaur, a giant ape, or what have you. For the duration of the *polymorph* effect, the simulacrum **effectively does not exist**, so none of it's restrictions apply to the new replacement.

A *[true polymorphed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* creature can regain hit points through resting (*polymorph* doesn't last long enough to complete a short rest to use hit dice, let alone a long rest). Using *true polymorph* also lets you potentially pick something with *regeneration*, a feature not found on any beast I'm aware of.

> The target assumes the hit points of its new form. When it reverts to its normal form, the creature returns to the number of hit points it had before it transformed.

When the *polymorph* effect expires and the creature resumes being a *simulacrum*, it has however many hit points it had before the *polymorph*. Of course, that's how it works for any other creature, too.

Answer (score -5):

I'd say no.

True Polymorph must target a creature or non-magical object. Simulacrum is an illusion. It is not a creature, and it certainly isn't non-magical.

Comment: You might want to quote and cite the *simulacrum* spell with regards to it not being a creature, that isn't quite obvious to me and your answer hinges on it.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: **"Simulacrum:** [...] The duplicate is a creature [...] and [can] be affected as a normal creature."
So, yeah, True Polymorph *can* affect Simulacrum.